# Zend_Form_Multicheckbox multiOptions with HTML in it

Tags: zend-framework, forms

For my form I need a checkbox with a single options "I accept the eligibility requirements", where "eligibility requirements" should be linked to a popup with the eligibility requirements in it.

This is my current code:

```
$teilnahmebedingungenArray = array('akzeptiere' => "Ich akzeptiere die <a href='foo.html'>Teilnahmebedingungen</a>");    

new Zend_Form_Element_Multicheckbox(
                    'teilnahmebedingungen', 
                    array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => null,
                        'multiOptions' => $teilnahmebedingungenArray,
                        'registerInArrayValidator' => false,
                        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                        'validators' => array(
                            array('NotEmpty', false, array('messages' => 'Sie müssen die Teilnahmebedingungen akzeptieren um am Wettbewerb teilzunehmen.'))
                        ),
                        'decorators' => $this->getQuestionDecorators(),
                    )
                ),
```

Zend_Form_Multicheckbox doesn't allow me to use HTML code in it's multioption. Is there an easy way to allow it or would you choose another way to solve the case? I don't want to set the eligibility requirements as a description.

Best regards,
Nico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding`'escape' => false` option should do the trick, e.g.

```
new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox(
                    'teilnahmebedingungen', 
                    array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => null,
                        'escape' => false
                         // the rest
```